# rails active record has_many custom query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many

is it possible to have an active record has_many associations, but i have a specific condition.

```
class Team < AR
  has_many :matches, query: 'team1 == ID or team2 == ID'
end

class Match < AR
  attr_accessible :team1, :team2
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a potential solution:

```
class Team < AR
  def matches
    Match.where("team1 = ? or team2 = ?", id, id) # or: { team1: id, team2: id }
  end
end
```

Comment: By doing the second approach, should i then remove the has many association?

Comment: Yes, and replace `#{ID}` with `#{id}` and single quotes with double quotes. Note that you'll loose many benefits of having an association, like caching. Each time you call `Team#matches` you'll get a new `Relation` object that will trigger a new database request.

Comment: would it help to store the `Relation` object? I am not sure myself, but I think that will prevent creating another object right?

Comment: The second approach actually won't trigger the database right away. Not from my experience, anyway - `.where()` doesn't do this (at least no it recent versions of Rails), so you can chain other DB-query-modifying stuff on the request and it will work as a single query even with the second example.

Comment: Also, yes, the second approach means you should remove the `has_many`. :)

Comment: Are those queries SQL injection-safe?

Comment: @CharlesBrocchiero No! Do not interpolate the Strings as I wrote on here. My apologies it was written when I was fairly new. Use`?` and additional args for the ids.

Comment: @CharlesBrocchiero I have deleted the first idea, and updated the second one to be sql-injection safe. Thank you for asking that / pointing it out. Hopefully people aren’t running the unsafe code.

Comment: Alright, glad to be of help! I had a hunch but didn't have time to look into it yet. That looks better!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `finder_sql` but it will be deprecated in Rails 4 and I'm not sure if there's a new way to do this:

```
class Team < AR
  has_many :matches, finder_sql: proc { "SELECT * FROM matches WHERE (matches.team1 = #{id} or matches.team2 = #{id})" }
end
```

Another solution:

```
class Team < AR
  has_many :matches_as_team1, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "team1"
  has_many :matches_as_team2, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "team2"
  def matches
    matches_as_team1 | matches_as_team2
  end
end
```

In this solution, the result of `Team#matches` is an array, not a `Relation`, so you won't be able to do things like `team.matches.limit(10)`.

Comment: i prefer to have relation capabilities.

Comment: Then use the first solution with `finder_sql`.

Comment: Note that the `finder_sql` must take a `proc`. A `->` is not sufficient

Comment: To make result an `relation` use `matches_as_team1.or(matches_as_team2)`

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer keeping your association as normal and apply query later on with where condition.

```
class Team < AR
  has_many :matches

  scope :team_details, lambda {|id1,id2| matches.where("team1 = ? OR team2 = ?",id1,id2)} 
end
```

team (object of Team)

Then call

```
team.team_details(id1,id2)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the `#{}` notation with the `?` - it's used inside Strings, but your variables are being referenced outside the String.